# Meteor event fires the wrong method

Tags: javascript, meteor

This Meteor client code when the button `CLEAR` is hit, the browser console prints `Check entries` but that is only expected to fire when the `INFO` buttons is clicked and only if `plate` is null.
What did I do wrong and how to fix it? thx

```
Template.body.events({
  'submit form': function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   footerInfo();
 }
});

Template.footer.events({
  'click #clear': () => {
    Session.set('busy', false);
    document.getElementById('plate').value = '';
    Session.set('plate', '');
    searching = '';
  },
  'click #info': () => {
    footerInfo();
  }
});

footerInfo = () => {
  let plate = document.getElementById('plate').value;
  if (!plate) {
    console.log('Check entries');  //<-- prints even when CLEAR is clicked.
    Session.set('busy', false);
    return;
  }
  Session.set('plate', plate);
  let doc = myCol.findOne({plate: Session.get('plate')});
};
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="content">
      <form>
        <button type="submit" style="display:none"></button>
            {{> content}}
            {{> footer}}
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<template name="content">
    <input type="text" id="plate" autocomplete="off">
</template>

<template name="footer">
  <footer>
    <button id="clear">CLEAR</button>
    <button id="info">INFO</button>
  </footer>
</template>
```

Comment: i swear i've seen this code before. did you post it in a different question? or is this for a homework assignment?

Comment: @zim not a homework assignment.

Comment: both those buttons are inside a form, and i reckon you're not handling the form submission correctly. Simplify! comment out your logic and put nothing more than console logs in each event handler to see if only the expected handler is being invoked on a button press, or if both are.

Comment: adding type `<button type='button'>....</button>`

Comment: @zim you are right. `'submit form'` was firing both buttons. But how can this be fixed. add condition in the `submit form` event or there is a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in general, you'd probably want to use Meteor form submit functionality to handle this (c.f. https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/forms-and-events) but your setup is a little weird because the buttons are in a different template than the form is in.

here, i would likely keep the overall structure, and add a "event.preventDefault()" at the top of each event handler.

if for some reason that doesn't work, also add an "event.stopImmediatePropagation()".

but i think this should do it:

```
Template.footer.events({
  'click #clear': (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    Session.set('busy', false);
    document.getElementById('plate').value = '';
    Session.set('plate', '');
    searching = '';
  },
  'click #info': (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    footerInfo();
  }
});
```